# Docker - PostgreSQL - Spring Boot Error: db does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I have a very simple crud application in Spring Boot. I want to dockerize this project.

My Dockerfile is follow code (Dockerfile is in ROOT folder)

```
FROM openjdk:11
COPY /target/crudapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/app/
WORKDIR /usr/app
RUN sh -c 'touch basic-spring-boot-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
ARG JAR_FILE=target/basic-spring-boot-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","crudapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

And my docker-compose.yml file is follow code (docker-compose.yml file is in src/main/docker)

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    image: 'crudapp:latest'
    build:
      context: ../../.././
    container_name: ktun-crudapp
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/studentdb
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=root
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update

  db:
    image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=studentdb
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
```

my proje structure is the following image

[image]

And you can see my Dockerfile, my project jar file and my docker-compose.yml file.

When i start my docker-compose.yml file with `docker-compose up` command, give me an error following image in cmd;

[image]

How can i fix.?

Comment: Can you check the database logs together with the app logs to make sure that Postgres has finished creating the database when you try to connect to it?

Comment: @HansKilian firstly hello, thank your for command.

When i run docker compose file, postgresql work wihtout any error. But studentdb is not created. Actually now, give me another errors. :D 

If you want, you can check following link;
Code(https://github.com/fsk/ktun-code-presentation)